# How can I record gameplay on a Mac?

Tags: macos, recording

I can find plenty of information on recording programs for Windows, but information for OS X is much harder to find. What are the requirements and steps for recording gameplay on a Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windowed games (such as Minecraft), QuickTime does a good enough job, just drag around the gameplay window. It doesn't seem to impact framerate too much, although it doesn't have an overlay like Fraps so it's hard to tell.

Comment: I've found just the opposite. QuickTime has terrible performance on my mac, and it's no sloucher. It's a mid-2009 MacBook Pro, 8 GB of RAM, 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT Graphics, and I get about 10 FPS when playing minecraft & recording. That's why I use [Snapz Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks for the info. I just did a trial run on my '12 MBP and it was fine with reasonable settings. I'll do some more extensive testing this evening.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I've also been recommended [iShowU HD](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu-hd/), which is a little cheaper.